# How to create a flashlight light

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light

I just wanted to know how to create a flashlight lighting as it is showed in the pic[image: FNAF Flashlight]

I have tried to create a spot light, but it doesn't works. Could anyone help?
Thanks!

Comment: Why doesn't a spot lamp work?

Comment: Are you using BR or Cycles?

Comment: Um... Use a texture as your spotlight?

Comment: I'm using Cycles. The spot doesnt wriks beacause even with 1000000 of light stregnht it doesnt works...

Comment: I've played the *'Five nights at freddy's 4'* game recently and had a deja vu. The game location looked familiar to the image I had seen before. And this is the image. Now I am even more scared :O.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## BLENDER RENDER

You may achieve it giving the ***Spot Light*** a ***texture***.
[image]
[image]

Add a ***Spot Light*** (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>-->*Lamp*-->*Spot*), go to ***Lamp Data*** header and set up the settings depending on your needs.
[image]

Prepare your texture (you may find similar one in the net).
[image]

With a lamp still selected go to the ***Texture*** header, click a little *bulb icon*, add your texture and set the mapping coordinates to ***View***.
[image]

## CYCLES RENDER

You may achieve it adding two ***Spot Lights*** with different settings.
[image]

Play with the ***Strenght***, ***Size*** and ***Blend*** settings for different lamps. When finished you may parent one lamp to another with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to make them move together.
[image]

***EDIT:*** This method works well in *Blender Render* also.

Answer (score 7):

Try:

- In World Settings set Surface color to black
- Turn the Spot Lamp Strength way up, like to 2000 and then adjust to suit

[image: World Settings]

[image: Spot Lamp Strength]

[image]

Add another spot to get the concentric look in the lighting of your example.

Comment: What should be know about Blender that didn't allow original poster's setup to work? IOW, why didn't it work?