# how to attach spot lamp to camera and make lamp always face out from camera like headlamp?

Tags: camera

still new to Blender and this forum.
I'm wondering how to attach a spot lamp to camera and make lamp always face out from camera like a headlamp? So as the camera moves around, the spot lamp light is always facing straight out from the camera just like a cave explorers lamp on their helmet. So wherever the camera goes, and wherever it points, a nice bright spotlight is shining the way, shining brightly on anything the camera looks at?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may do it ***parenting*** the *spot light* to the *camera* or using the ***child of*** or ***copy transforms*** constraints.
[image]

Select the *spot light*, then the *camera* and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>-->Object (Keep Transform).
[image]

Select the *spot light*, go to the *Constraints* header and set the *camera* as a target.
[image]
[image]

***Note:*** If you want to go further with the more detailed lighting please see this: [How to create a flashlight light](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52587/how-to-create-a-flashlight-light) May be helpul for you.

Comment: Note that when parenting is that if lamp and the camera are not in the same place, the lamp won't move to the camera's location, so there will be an offset.

Comment: @Paul Gonet Thank you very much. And for the very quick response, much appreciated. Yes all three techniques work. I for some reason was trying Track To which didn't do it. Note that is seems I had to do a lot of preparations first, like clearing rotations, cursor to selection, selection to cursor, before any parenting, constraints, etc...for anyone else new to this.

Comment: @cegaton Thanks for mentioning to watch out about the the offset. And it got me thinking that offset will come in handy I'm sure at some point when used intentionally.

Answer (score 5):

Select the light and add a child of Constraint, then select the camera as target. If you move the camera the light will do the same thing.

[image]

Comment: Yes, thank you very much, that works great. One note, it seems I had to select "set inverse" for it to work.